# How do i delete values from a dictionary that are less than 7 letters long?

Tags: python-3.x

i have been stuck on this small piece of code for quite a while and was wondering if anyone could help fix my problem or show me how to code it. The output i'm trying to get is phones : ['motorolla', 'oneplus']
i'm basically trying to output phone names longer than 7 letters, thanks in advance

```
def main():

    my_dict = {'phones': ['galaxy', 'oneplus', 'google', 'apple', 'motorolla']}
    items_list = list(my_dict.items())
    for key, value in items_list:
         if len(value) < 7:
            del my_dict[value]
    return my_dict


def print_dict_in_key_order(a_dict):
    all_keys = list(a_dict.keys())
    all_keys.sort()
    for key in all_keys:
        print(key, ":", a_dict[key])

main()
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do? Your dictionary has exactly one entry, so what you seem to want is to delete items from a list; the usual way is to use a list comprehension to filter: `items_list = [x for x in my_dict['phones'] if len(x) >= 7]` should return you a list of all items 7 or more characters long.

Comment: def main():
    
    my_dict = {'phones': ['galaxy', 'oneplus', 'google', 'Apple', 'Motorolla']}
    items_list = [x for x in my_dict['phones'] if len(x) >= 7]
    return my_dict

def print_dict_in_key_order(a_dict):
    all_keys = list(a_dict.keys())
    all_keys.sort()
    for key in all_keys:
        print(key, ":", a_dict[key])
main()

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():

my_dict = {'phones': ['galaxy', 'oneplus', 'google', 'apple', 'motorolla']}
#items_list = list(my_dict.items())
for key in my_dict:
     new_list=[]
     for value in my_dict[key]:
         if len(value)>=7:
             new_list.append(value)
     my_dict[key]=new_list
     print('{}:'.format(key),new_list)
print(my_dict)

return my_dict
```

main()

```
main()
```

I think this is easier for you to understand.

Comment: Ken Y-N is also right, you need to update the dict after you get items_list using my_dict['phone']=items_list.

Comment: sorry to bother you but how would i change the code to make it output exactly phones : ['oneplus', 'motorolla'] ? i'm currently getting {'phones': ['oneplus', 'motorolla']}. so how do i get rid of the curly brackets?

Comment: Oh, this is a dictionary, you want to print it out like that?

Comment: yeah exactly like phones: ['oneplus', motorolla]

Comment: I will change my code above. You are really new to python. Google is better for you to learn quickly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a dictionary comprehension to rebuild the dictionary, e.g.:

```
def main():
    my_dict = {'phones': ['galaxy', 'oneplus', 'google', 'apple', 'motorolla']}
    return {k: sorted(v for v in vs if len(v) >= 7) for k, vs in my_dict.items()}

In []:
main()

Out[]:
{'phones': ['motorolla', 'oneplus']}
```

If you just want the phones then you can replace the comprehension with:

```
    return sorted(v for vs in my_dict.values() for v in vs if len(v) >= 7)
```

Comment: looks complex to me

Comment: `list` and `dict` [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are a key feature of python.

Comment: hey guys just one last question, how would i sort the list in alphabetical order? right now i'm getting phones: ['oneplus', 'motorolla'], i tried new_list.sort(), but that didn't work

Comment: hey nvm guys i got it

Comment: Reading some introductory python learning materials may help you, many of the questions you are raising are covered in introductory material.